# Oh My Bash problem

Tags: bash, themes, cd

After I installed oh my bash, I used some themes like agnoster for my bash and i started to code, but when I used command cd and pressed tab it said there's about 360 possiblities and there was at most 20 directories in my home directory.

[image]

I don't know it's for om my bash but when I turn theme to font this issue goes away.

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: There will be lots of hidden directories (prefixed with dot, like `.ssh` and `.git`) which are valid to `cd` into.

Comment: i know but not 363

Comment: `ls -a -1 | wc -l` will tell you how many